# Как создать список объектов класса в с++?

Tags: c++, списки, классы

Требуется обработать данные, которые находятся или, вернее, формируются в списке объектов класса. Возникает ряд общих вопросов: 
Каким образом создается список, состоящий из объектов класса? 
Какие должны быть поля в списке для отображения объекта класса?
Как инициализировать объект класса при создании элемента списка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В C++ для таких целей используются стандартные контейнеры. В зависимости от нужных вам операций и их требуемой производительности, вам подойдёт [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (обычно то, что надо), [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) или [другие](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) контейнеры. Писать контейнер самому в подавляющем большинстве случаев нерационально.
2. По поводу полей, вам не нужно об этом думать, если вы пользуетесь стандартным контейнером.
3. Контейнеры содержат по существу *копии*  положенных туда объектов. Для того, чтобы избежать потенциально дорогого копирования, возможно, стоит располагать объекты в куче и держать в контейнере (возможно, [«умные»](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) указатели на них. Таким образом, инициализация тривиальна. Если ваш контейнер всё же будет содержать сами объекты, вам может понадобиться конструктор копирования (т. к. например `std::vector` копирует объекты при изменении размера), а для добавления объекта разумно воспользоваться функцией наподобие [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), которая конструирует объект прямо в контейнере.